# xmlrpc unsupported method call with php

Tags: php, xmlhttprequest, xml-rpc

I have a method on a remote IIS server at somefile.ashx, one of the methods I'm trying to call is 'UserLogInReq'.

UserLogInReq has the following members:

String: Username 
String: Password 
String: ClientType

This is my script so far:

```
$request = xmlrpc_encode_request('UserLogInReq', array("UserName" => '$username',"Password" =>'$password',"ClientType" => ''));

$context = stream_context_create(array('http' => array(
'method' => "POST",
'header' => "Content-Type: text/xml",
'content' => $request
)));

$file = file_get_contents("http://someserver/somepage.ashx", false, $context);

$response = xmlrpc_decode($file);

if ($response && xmlrpc_is_fault($response)) {
  trigger_error("xmlrpc: $response[faultString] ($response[faultCode])");
} else {
  print_r($response);
}
```

When I navigate to my web-service page, at somepage.ashx, this method is listed, with all of those members. However, when I run this script, I am getting:

```
Notice: unsupported method called: UserLogInReq (0)
```

All the help I could find is somehow un-related to a generic xml-rpc hookup/call.

Is this a permissions problem with the web-service?
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being a misunderstanding on my part. XML-RPC requriers structs, which equate to nested arrays in php. I just had to go down a few levels on the php arrays.